# Window icon for Gtk.MessageDialog?

Tags: gtk, messagedialog

I was wondering if it was possible to have a window icon placed in the dock bar for a generic MessageDialog.

For any other window, I can easily set the icon from a file; and every time I open or I hide a window, then the relative windows icon is showed in the dock bar.
I tried by different ways but i'm not able.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean giving the window an icon or having the window listed in the window manager's window list? There's functions for both, and since GtkMessageDialog is derived from GtkWindow, you should be able to call them...

Comment: I can use set_icon_from_file() but actually it doesn't work